# Set world's spawn to the center of a block

Tags: java, bukkit

I recently discovered that when I executed the command /set spawn  and then ran /spawn I got teleported to the bottom right corner of the block, which is not my intended behaviour. I tried changing it but couldn't find the solution.

I'm pretty sure it's possible to set the spawn point to the center of a block. How can I do it?

```
p.getWorld().setSpawnLocation(p.getLocation().getBlockX(), p.getLocation().getBlockY() , p.getLocation().getBlockZ());
```

Comment: Can you show me the code that actually places you, this one just stores the block location.

Comment: p.teleport(p.getWorld().getSpawnLocation());

Comment: Okay, let me poke around in Bukkit's source for a minute.

Comment: @InfernoArtz Welcome to SO! If you found your answer, don't forget to mark it as accepted! It will help future users that might have the same doubts as you.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to set the spawning location to the center of a block as I recall. However you can easily teleport to the center of a block.

```
player.teleport(new Location(Bukkit.getWorld("worldName"), 100.5, 50, 100.5));
```

If you want players to spawn at these coordinates when they die, listen for the `PlayerRespawnEvent`:

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerRespawn(PlayerRespawnEvent event) {
    event.getPlayer().teleport(new Location(Bukkit.getWorld("worldName"), 100.5, 50, 100.5));
}
```

Also listen for the `onPlayerJoin` event if you wish them to teleport there on login.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, haven't done Java in a wile so here goes take your teleport line, `p.teleport(p.getWorld().getSpawnLocation());` and replace it with this.

```
Location centerblock = new Location(p.getWorld(), p.getWorld().getSpawnLocation().getX() + 0.5, p.getWorld().getSpawnLocation().gety(), p.getWorld().getSpawnLocation().getZ() + 0.5);
p.teleport(centerblock);
```

Basically just take the spawn location, and add 0.5 blocks to the X and Z co-ordinates, that "should" put you in the center.

Let me know if this does not work and I will try again and edit it.

Comment: But what about centering a effect? How does that work?

Comment: Does it use the Location object like teleporting does, if so just get the original target and add 0.5 to X and Z.

Comment: When the player run /fix it launches an effect, but its offcentered, so not connected to the spawn related.

Comment: Yeah, you are basically just taking the block and moving the position over one half (0.5). The game then handles all the fun bits like turning 16.5 into where on the screen that actually is.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's **not possible** to set the center of a block as the World's spawn point.

The reason for that is the signature of the method setSpawnPoint.

```
World.setSpawnPoint(int x, int y, int z)
```

Due to being integers, the only possible point would not be the center, as the center of a block is the half of it's coordintes, so if a block is at position x=100, y=100 and z=100, its center is x= 100.5, y=100 and z= 100.5.

As setSpawnPoint only accepts integer, that method isn't possible.

---

However, **there is a workaround**:

You can define the location of your world's spawn point and teleport players there if there's no bed respawn location.

```
Location l = new Location(World w, x + 0.5, y, z + 0.5)
```

Being w, x, y and z the location's world, x coordinate, y coordinate and z coordinate, respectfully.

And handle your PlayerRespawnEvent:

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerRespawn(PlayerRespawnEvent e) {
   Player player = e.getPlayer();
   Location bedSpawn = player.getBedSpawnLocation();    //Null if there is no spawn

    if (bedSpawn == null) {
        player.teleport(l);
    }
}
```